# Internal Server Error al incluir imágenes con mpdf con rutas de mi mismo dominio

Tags: php, mpdf, ubuntu-server

Estoy experimentando un error muy extraño y espero puedan ayudarme. Mi servidor me marca un `Internal Server Error` cuando trato de incluir un `<img>`.

Tengo este código donde uso `mpdf` para crear mi pdf:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('s', $size);
$mpdf->AddPage('', // L - landscape, P - portrait 
    '', '', '', '',
    10, // margin_left
    10, // margin right
    0, // margin top
    0, // margin bottom
    26, // margin header
0
); // margin footer
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<img src="https://www.mipagina.com/miimagen.jpg">', 2);
$mpdf->Output($file_name . ".pdf",'I');
```

Curiosamente cuando la misma imagen la subo en otro servidor como sustituyendo `https://www.mipagina.com/miimagen.jpg` por `https://i.imgur.com/AKcCbU5.jpg` el pdf carga sin problema, quedando mi código así:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('s', $size);
$mpdf->AddPage('', // L - landscape, P - portrait 
    '', '', '', '',
    10, // margin_left
    10, // margin right
    0, // margin top
    0, // margin bottom
    26, // margin header
0
); // margin footer
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<img src="https://i.imgur.com/AKcCbU5.jpg">', 2);
$mpdf->Output($file_name . ".pdf",'I');
```

Creo que pueda deberse a una mala configuración de mi servidor web. Siento que rechaza de alguna manera que una imagen se cargue. Estoy ocupando `Ubuntu Server 18.04` y ya revisé que `allow_url_fopen` estuviera activo pero no logro dar con la solución.

En mi log de apache no me dice mucho, solo me sale algo como `graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL` y no sé si signifique algo relevante, ya que hasta donde estuve investigando no es algo que tenga que ver con mi problema.

Cualquier ayuda significa mucho para mí. Gracias.

Comment: crea un archivo de nombre `randomstring.php` con `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` para acceder por url y verificar donde se guarda el log de errores de php, una vez localizado borras el archivo

Comment: como adelanto puede ser que curl o php no encuentren el certificado del servidor (https)

Comment: Gracias @aloMalbarez Me pareció interesante lo que mencionas, intenté quitarle el https a mi url de mi dominio y sigue en las mismas.

Comment: un wget del file desde consola? tal vez el servidor no sepa su nombre desde localhost

Comment: Interesante. Al hacer esto desde consola se queda estancado indicando esto: `https://erp.xxxxxxxxxxx.mx/assets/images/pase-v2-sky-jpg.jpg
Resolving erp.xxxxxxxxxxx.mx (erp.xxxxxxxxxxx.mx)... 189.171.189.xxx
Connecting to erp.xxxxxxxxxxx.mx (erp.xxxxxxxxxxx.mx)|189.171.189.xxx|:443...`

Comment: el tamaño del pdf no importa? como workaround hasta que configures el server podes meterle un src=data:image/jpeg;base64,   leer el archivo directo de disco y basencodearlo como string

Comment: seguro puedo hacer eso, buena idea en lo que queda bien configurado, tendrás aparte una idea de cómo solucionar el que desconoce wget con el https? puede ser como dices que no reconoce el ssl, pero se me hace raro porque mi sitio funciona bien con https y las <img> sin usar mpdf en una página web en general sí funcionan bien

Comment: es por experiencia lo del https, las librerías tratan de resolver localmente y si curl o php no encuentran el certificado y todo el chain el https desde el mismo servidor falla. pero el error es evidente. un loop infinito puede ser que tengas que poner el dominio en `/etc/hosts` revisar si `/etc/hosts.conf` tiene en el order  consultar el dns, y también ver `/etc/nsswitch.conf` si está la opción dns, puede que sea el firewall también

Comment: vale, en realidad uso webmin pero voy a tratar de investigar lo que me dices, quizá sí sea por el firewall y el loop infinito, gracias!

Comment: webmin lo tiene bastante sencillo: hay que chequear/setear el order: hosts, dns, local hostname